# Run PowerShell script as different user and hidden window from another PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I need to run a PowerShell script from another PowerShell script as different user and hidden window.

What do I have so far:

```
Start-Process powershell '& C:\test.ps1' -WindowStyle Hidden -Credential $cred
```

where `$cred` is a `PSCredential` object. The `test.ps1` script is for testing purposes one line with `Remove-Item`. As I can still see the file not being removed I can tell that the script is not being run.

**EDIT**

My original intention is to run regedit script but when I was implementing `Start-Job` answer (below) I've got this error:

```
Start-Job : The value of the FilePath parameter must be a Windows PowerShell script file. Enter th
e path to a file with a .ps1 file name extension and try the command again.
```

Comment: Because the question is so common, I would point out that a `PSCredential` object for a user that's a member of `Administrators` won't run elevated using this technique. You would have to use the `Runas` verb for that. (I don't know whether that's your intention or not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `jobs` for this. As the [Powershell documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Start-Job?view=powershell-5.0) says

> A Windows PowerShell background job runs a command without interacting
>   with the current session.

```
PS> $myJob = Start-Job -FilePath C:\test.ps1 -Credential $cred
```

To get the result/output of the job, use `Receive-Job`

```
PS> $myJob | Receive-Job -Keep
```

Comment: tried your solution and it works perfectly with powershell scripts but not with regedit script. thought that it would be the same, damn powershell...

Comment: The file `c:\test.ps1`should contain `regedit.exe /s c:\file.reg`, or you could pass a scriptblock to `Start-Job` like so: `Start-Job -ScriptBlock {regedit /s c:\file.reg} -Credential $cred`

Answer (score 0):

You can run the PowerShell scripts through task scheduler. I'm not sure if it is your goal, but it will let you execute PowerShell scripts on a user's session using their credentials.

I'll let you Google the how to, to fit your needs.